# Phpmyadmin error report

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: phpmyadmin error report]

HI guys I'm sorry i'm just a newbie in programming. I don't understand this error. I try researching but i cant get a right answer. I'm always ignoring this error message and I'm wondering if it will affect later on my projects?

Comment: Download a newer version. This error was apparently fixed in 4.5. https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11747 https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12099

Comment: @aynber I suggest that you post this as an answer as it's the best solution to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';** in the config.inc.php file in phpmyadmin root folder. It will hide all notices.

Also, provide a value to $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'KJSFDHJDFsdjsgs*&@&bsjdsb334';

**Note**: *In case you have installed fresh phpmyadmin. Then make a new file config.inc.php and copy all the default data from config.sample.inc.php file.*